# Reverse engineering to get CRC16 Polynomial

Tags: python, c, reverse, crc16

I'm trying to find an efficient way to calculate the CRC16 polynomial using the base value and the CRC16 output.
An example to be more clear:

```
y = CRC16(x)
```

How can I find the polynomial used by CRC16 function to evaluate y?
I'm using C and Python to create some executable (for test purposes).

Comment: I'd start by working with the simplest possible input, an empty string or one consisting of a single zero byte.

Comment: There are only 32K possible values for a 17-bit number with both high and low bits set.  Why are you bringing up efficiency?

Comment: Are you saying you have access to a function `CRC16()`, and you would like to re-implement that function?  If so, please provide the CRC returned by that function for the nine bytes (in ASCII): "123456789".

Comment: I have 2 bytes that are the output of the CRC16 function and then I have the original data. I'm trying to understand what kind of polynomial is used by the CRC function to obtain that specific 2 bytes starting from that specific original data.

Answer (score 0):

The list of the polynomials for CRC checking can be found here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks

In particular, you probably want the polynomial CRC-16-ANSI

[image]

Comment: i think CRC-16-CCITT is used more, 
CCITT: Comité Consultatif International Téléphonique et Télégraphique
The International Telegraph and Telephone Consultative Committe, now ITU-T

Answer (score 0):

Lammert Bies has an excellent [page](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html) with references and C libraries for different methods for CRC-16.

Mainly, it contains an online calculator that you can use to immediately see if what you want is one of the well know methods.

If it is, the C libraries give immediately an optimised implementation of a CRC calculator, and they can easily be translated in Python. You will find an example for CRC-CCITT XMODEM variant in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25259157/3545273) from mine

Comment: I know this is not far from a link only answer, but I really do not know how to do it differently : first link **has** to be a link since it is an online calculator, and second is just an example for previous explaination.